# Можно ли использовать имена перед их включением?

Tags: c++, gcc, include

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::string{"Hello, world!\n"};
}

#include <string>
```

Почему эта программа работает, ведь я включил `std::string` после использования? Соответствует ли она стандарту?

Comment: Ваш инклуд в глобальной области видимости - она обрабатывается в первую очередь. Но лучше так не делать :)

Comment: а попробуй удалить include <string>

Comment: @TigerTV.ru это ни чего не покажет, даже если будет выполняться. Есть настройки в IDE, которые позволяют подключать библиотеки автоматом

Comment: @Виктор, [apparently <iostream> includes <string>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506108/9210255)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В стандарте определено, что заданный тип данных должен быть определен в заданном заголовочном файле, но не обязывает компилятор (или поставщика STL), определять в заголовочном файле только те сущности, которые упомянуты в стандарте.

Компилятор имеет право включить одни заголовочные файлы в другие, но не обязан это делать.

Разные компиляторы имеют право вести себя по разному на этом коде: https://godbolt.org/z/9T8zTT3sb

Т.е. правило "используешь тип - подключи заголовочный файл" является правилом для программиста, и компилятор не обязан отслеживать его соблюдения.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать классы перед их объявлением - нет. Если тип не известен будет ошибка компиляции. У вас работает и с добавлением в конце и без добавления, потому-что этот заголовочный файл кто-то уже загрузил. Может быть даже и `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы про **пре**процессор слышали? Он работает **до** начала компиляции. А #include – именно его директива, никаких имён не создающая. Имя объявлено во включаемом файле и это std::string, а не <string>. Ну и кто сказал, что в <iostream> или во включенном в него файле или в файле, включенном в файл, включенный в <iostream>, или в файле, включенном в файл,..., включенный в <iostream> нет строки

```
    class std::string;
```

, не определяющей класс и его имя, но сообщающей, что класс и его имя будут объявлены позже, что позволяет использовать это имя до его объявления, но при условии, что позже оно будет объявлено и описано? Вы прочитали весь файл <iostream>, все файлы, включенные в <iostream>, все файлы, включенные в файлы, включенные в <iostream>, все файлы, включенные в файлы,..., включенные в файл <iostream>? Ни сам компилятор этого вообще не умеет, а препроцессор не делает этого по собственной инициативе, но это могли сделать разработчики. Они вообще имеют право написать всё, что прямо не противоречит стандарту. А могу и не писать любой кусок, который прямо не требуется стандартом. Лишь бы к итоге не было поведения, прямо противоречащего стандарту и спецификациям, и было всё поведение, прямо в стандарте и спецификациями описанное. Включая спецификации на конкретные классы и прочие типы. Я вообще лишь однажды использовал все свои функции только не менее раза после объявления. В остальных моих проектах все мои функции вызываются **только до** своего объявления. Это делается предварительной декларацией: сначала пишу:

```
    <тип функции> <имя функции>(<список формальных параметров через запятую>);
```

, потом использую функцию, а только потом её объявляю и никаких гвоздёв. Даже если я хочу что-то проверить, то и тогда пишу именно так. Всего лишь из-за того, что мне это больше нравится визуально.